# Using surf to make a 3d imshow

Tags: python, 3d, surf, mayavi, imshow

I'm struggling with some difficulties to understand how surf really works and how can I use it's approach in my context. I'm trying to use surf from Mayavi to plot a 3D representation of a 2D imshow(). I do know know if it's the correct path so I'm able to use other suggestions also.

Basically I have reached this so far: **data** is an array that contains the values respectfully to x and y coordinates. Thus, the shape of data is (50L, 50L) and each element corresponds to the value of the pairs of my 50*50 elements.

```
imshow(data, cmap=cm.jet, origin='upper', interpolation=None) # My 2D imshow... working fine here.

# Trying to have a 3D representation
nx = linspace(0, 4, 50)
ny = linspace(0, 4, 50)
x_3d, y_3d = meshgrid(nx, ny)
s = surf(x_3d, y_3d, data)
```

The script launches with no errors, however I do not have any visualization on the Mayavi scene.

Thanks for your help, and if anyone has a better suggestion of how to plot a 3D representation of a 2D imshow I'm happy to accept also.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `mlab.show()` command at the end and surf needs three arguments I think x and y are just the position of your points, you need a third array to determine the z-coordinate.